# How to read an escaped table in SQL Server from R DBI?

Tags: r, sql-server, dbi, nanodbc

I was able to use `DBI::dbWriteTable` to write a table with a non-standard name `[name@place:funny/pages]`, but I am unable to read it back in with `DBI::dbReadTable`.

When I try with:

```
dbReadTable(con, '[name@place:funny/pages]')
```

I see the error:

> Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1655: 00000: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Serv [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][S L Serv  'SELECT * FROM "[name@place:funny/pages]"'

`sessionInfo` tells me I am using `odbc_1.3.2` and `DBI_1.1.1`.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way around the problem? I need to use that naming scheme to maintain compatibility with established processes.

I am able to read this table without issue from SQL with:

```
select * from [name@place:funny/pages]
```

Comment: `name@place:/funny/pages` is not the same as `name@place:funny/pages`.

Comment: That is true! However, that was a typo on my part in writing the question. It seems like the real problem is that nanodbc adds doublequotes. It doesn't do this with a direct SQL call.

Comment: I figured out that I didn't need to include the brackets at all.

Comment: I am absolutely curious in what context a SQL table name like that seems reasonable ... perhaps I've been encased too long in the fold of SQL naming conventions/restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to not include brackets at all.